# Issue with json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) for flask app

Tags: python, json

**Hi, I don't really know how to debug the error "json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)", could someone help please?**

**Here are my routes**

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def home():
    race = requests.get('http://service_2:5000/get/race').json()
    clas = requests.get('http://service_3:5000/get/class').json()

    data = [race, clas]
    points = requests.post('http://service_4:5000/post/points', json=data).json()

    records = Character.query.order_by(Character.id.desc()).limit(15).all()

    outcome = Character(race=race, clas=clas, points=points)
    db.session.add(outcome)
    db.session.commit()

    return render_template('home.html', points=points, records=records)
```

**And my home.html**

```
<html>
{% block body %}
     <body style='background-color:rgb(35, 59, 110)'> <center>
     <h1>Generate your character here.</h1> </center>
{% endblock body %} </body> </html>
```

I'll really appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: One or both of the responses to the service requests are not JSON.  Try printing each response's `content` attribute before calling `.json()` to see which one is causing the problem.

Comment: snakecharmerb solution worked, thanks :)